# Where is there a good discussion of using python packages?

Tags: python, installation, package

Is there a good discussion of setup.py and python packages from the package user perspective? Then maybe also from the package developer viewpoint too?

Comment: what are you looking to learn?

Answer (score 3):

[The Hitchhiker's Guide to Packaging](http://guide.python-distribute.org/usage.html) is a good read. Covers everything from creating your own packaging to finding packages, installation, virtualenvs, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, the valid (though subjective) answer for your question would be "yes".

But I think you need the links. Well, from the package developer viewpoint, I had the very same question. In Python world, package management appears to be a bit of a mess at the moment. Here are some resources that I found useful:

- First, [James Bennet's (django dev) ‘On packaging’](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/dec/14/packaging/)
- [Ian Bicking's ‘Corrections To “On Packaging”’](http://blog.ianbicking.org/2008/12/14/a-few-corrections-to-on-packaging/)—*very* useful read, made finally clear for me the complicated relationship between `distribute` and `setuptools`, as well as many other things
- Occasionally, [Building and Distributing Packages with Distribute](http://packages.python.org/distribute/setuptools.html)
- `setup.py` files from different projects

(Though I also think it would be better if you tell us what exactly do you want to learn.)

Comment: I did ask "where" in the Question. :)

Right now, I want to learn the ins and out of deploying other people's packages. But, as I said, I want an introduction to the packaging process. I have packaged apps and libraries for various systems and understanding what goes in a package and how it works is informative to an app developer (which is apparently what I am now).

Comment: Okay, my misunderstanding. =) Well, as a general introduction, @zeekay's suggestion, Hitchhiker's Guide, is really good (despite still being unfinished). But I'd still recommend to check out James Bennet's and Ian Bicking's posts for some background info... and for general discussion of python package management.